# Call to undefined method TCG\Voyager\Voyager::canOrFail()

Tags: laravel, voyager

### Version information

- Laravel: v5.8.35
- Voyager: v1.2.7
- PHP: 7.2
- Database: mysql

### Description

> The left side links are not working after upgrading voyager

[image: Screenshot from 2019-09-26 00-51-30]

> After upgrading voyager its showing error on opening men builder

[image: Screenshot from 2019-09-26 00-47-37]

Answer (score 1):

The methods **can, canOrFail and canOrAbort** were removed in v1.0.12 and above have been removed now in favor of Policies and Gates.

Please check this https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/releases